# How to access child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery plugin. After rendering in the browser, the html layout is as following lines of code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="mce-container-body">
        ...
        <input type="text" id="textedit01">
        ...
    </div>
    <iframe>
        <html>
        ...
        <input id="submitbuttonid" type="submit" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $('#submitbuttonid"').click(function () {
                    var URL = "http://localhost:61222/14CommunityImages/hands.png";
                    var $container = $(this).parent();
                    $container.toggle();
                    $(".mce-container-body input", $container).val(URL);
                    tinyMCEPopup.close();
                });
            });

        </script>

        ...
        </html>
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the issue is that the code

```
var $container = $(this).parent();
$container.toggle();
$(".mce-container-body input", $container).val(URL);
```

is accessing the top level html elements. Basically I have to append url value in input tag which is inside .mce-container-body... Please help !!!

Comment: whether both the parent window and the iframe are from the same origin

Comment: yes these are rendered in same html page

Comment: You didn't understood Arun's question. Let me try in more simpler term, Do both belong to same domain?

Comment: you have given ID for that text field why you directly access is by using ID ie$("#textedit01").val(URL);

Comment: actually the id of text varies (is changed dynamically) at different run time

Comment: $(".mce-container-body input:first-child").val(URL);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.parent.$(".mce-container-body input").val(URL);
```

This should work for you if you have the source from the same domain in the iframe.

Comment: then the iframe is not on the same domain? Edited the code try it now, if not working, there must be Same Origin Policy problems!

Comment: can u please help me in getting id of <input type="text" id="textedit01"> so that we can write  parent.document.getElementById("mceu_96-inp").value = URL;

Comment: it's working but id is changed at different run time

Comment: `window.parent.$(".mce-container-body").child("input").attr("id");` but instead, do like this `window.parent.$(".mce-container-body").child("input").val(URL);` or you have more inputs there that must get different values?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access input element then please have a look in below JS code::

$(".mce-container-body").find("#textedit01").val(URL);

inside that click event.

Hope this will help you.